# Discord.js - choosing random image in my pc

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a command where !send image will send random specified image on my pc. this is my array of images
`const images = [
    '/mybot/images/any image i have there',
    'other images'
]`
and this is the way it is supposed to choose one

````
 if(message.content === prefix + 'send image')
    {
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} here you have image`, {
            file: RetardedImage[Math.floor(Math.random() * RetardedImage.length)]
        });
    }```

but it doesnt work and problem is that it doesnt even say error or something so i dont know what the problem is, can someone please help me?
````

Answer (score 0):

There's no `file` option for a message, it's called `files` and it's an array:

```js
 if(message.content === prefix + 'send image')
    {
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} here you have image`, {
            files: [
                {
                       name: "myimage.png",
                       attachment: RetardedImage[Math.floor(Math.random() * RetardedImage.length)]
                 }
             ]
        });
    }
```

This will send your file properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can make an attachment like this

```js
const attachment = new <Discord>.Attachment("PATH","NAME.EXTENSION")
message.channel.send(`blah blah`+attachment)
```